# cakephp download big file with header content-length missing

Tags: php, apache, cakephp-3.0

I have following code to download file in CakePHP 3.6:

```
public function download($id){
   $movie = $this->Movies->get($id)->toArray();
   $myfile = new File($movie['path'] . $movie['filename']);
   return $this->response->withFile($myfile->path, ['download' => true]);
}
```

In browser it has following headers:

```
accept-ranges:bytes
cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-disposition:attachment; filename="Film.avi"
content-encoding: gzip
content-transfer-encoding:binary
content-type:video/x-msvideo
date:Fri, 11 May 2018 15:43:47 GMT
expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:nginx
strict-transport-security:max-age=15768000
vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Firefox-Spdy:h2
```

I need to see progress % when downloading, It means Content-length header is missing.  When I added to function :

```
$s = $myfile->size();
$this->response->withFile($myfile->path, ['download']->true])->withHeader('Content-Length',$s);
```

Still no success. Can you help me please ? I missed whole day with this.
Something with qzip. I found that it should be disabled but I dont know how...

Comment: Why have you tagged this with apache, when the server header indicates that it's nginx?

Comment: I use synology server and it uses apache in web station.

Comment: Problem solved ! Must be  header("Content-Encoding: none");  then it works. I hope I help someone else with this.